# Compile-file with in-memory data instead of real file in Common Lisp

Tags: compiler-construction, common-lisp

Is there a way to achieve the effects of `compile-file` but not with a regular file on disk, but with a stream or just an in-memory string? (I.e. if I don't have a file and don't want to create temporary files out of this in-memory data)

**EDIT**

I'm thinking of the following use case: loading code from some other places, than the file system. For example from archives (similar to Java's jars or Python zip handling capabilities) or from the network. Maybe there may be alternative approaches to this, than just bending `compile-file` machinery.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I'm also interested in nonportable approaches

Comment: You probably know about this (http://xach.livejournal.com/131456.html), but I'm mentioning it here just in case. Peter Seibel's approach (mentioned in the above post - http://www.gigamonkeys.com/blog/2007/07/27/compiling-queries-without-eval.html) doesn't use `compile-file`, just `compile`, but maybe you can adapt your solution to use this? Or better, use trees of closures?

Comment: @MironBrezuleanu thanks for the link, but I'm really interested in compilation of certain units of code, as if they were in a file. I've updated the question to clarify this

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin from your edit I gather you want `load`, not `compile-file` (you mention 'loading code from some other places'). The CLHS entry for `compile-file` doesn't seem to imply that compiling a file also means loading. The CLHS entry for `load` mentions that the first argument can be a stream - isn't this what you need?

Comment: @MironBrezuleanu actually, I'm actually interested in both, because I was looking for ways to hook into ASDF. But you're right, that I didn't pay enough attention to the semantics of `load` being different from that of `compile-file`. At least for this use case, I think, it might actually be enough. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: perhaps with-compilation-unit can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first comment of Rainer Joswig nails it:

> Not in standard Common Lisp.

You can search in each implementation for the calls made from `compile-file` to see if the underlying implementation takes a stream.

If you want to achieve this by yourself, you'll be implementing a quite inefficient version of `compile-file` for input and output streams that generates loadable forms suitable for `load` or your own version of it.

Wrapping the compilation with `with-compilation-unit`, you'll have to take special care in `macroexpand`ing top-level forms, make sure that `progn` forms are treated like top-level forms, that `locally`, `macrolet` and `symbol-macrolet` forms establish bindings and process their forms as top-level with a non-null lexical enviroment (the manipulation of which is not portable either), and process `eval-when` forms, where some forms may be evaluated, processed or both. Then, generate externalizable forms, having care about what can be coalesced and what cannot (e.g. symbols and packages), calling `make-load-form` for `standard-object`, `structure-object` and `condition` instances, and taking special care for symbols and packages, such as checking if the stream to compile has a first non-atomic `in-package` form or not as to be able to signal an error if `load` is called with a different value of `*package*`.

And this are just the topmost steps for minimal compilation, more or less, without mentioning when does compilation actually happen (compile-time or load-time), `load-time-value` forms and many details. Some of the steps require code-walking.

My advice: just extract and save whatever source code you have from compressed data and sockets, then call `compile-file` followed by `load`, if you want to preserve compilation and loading semantics. For simpler things, you may do something like this:

```
(let* ((*package* *package*)
       (*readtable* *readtable*)
       (eof (copy-symbol 'eof))
       (form nil))
  (loop
    (setf form (read stream nil eof))
    (when (eq form eof)
      (return))
    (funcall (compile nil `(lambda () ,form)))))
```

If you don't care much about portability, make your implementation be able to handle compressed files by, for instance, supplying a decompressing external format to `compile-file`, and make your implementation be able to open URL's (URI's, IRI's, whatever you care about) instead of just pathnames. AFAIK, ABCL can open URL's for input. Yet, what would be the output file of `compile-file` when called with such an external resource? Maybe make your own `compile-and-load` which states the temporary file to use to both `compile-file`'s `output-file` key argument and to `load`.